# Xubuntu - No Network Devices Available

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet

I am using a Normande - VSIM1001 laptop that originally came with Windows 10 Home. I have installed Ubuntu on it but cannot get the wifi to work. I have also tried installing Xubuntu 20.04.3, but still encounter a `No network devices available` message.

When  I plug in a USB dongle, it recognizes it and works fine.

How can I resolve this issue?

Edit 1:

Output of `sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 36)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)
```

Output of `sudo lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 6080:8060 SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6321 Microdia USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlx28ee521df754
       serial: 28:ee:52:1d:f7:54
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.132 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Edit 2:

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio`:

```
[    2.408463] mmc2: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
```

Edit 3:

It is worth mentioning the with the Windows 10 it originally came with, the wifi worked. However, with Ubuntu and XUbuntu I am having this issue.

Comment: It will be important to know *which* network devices you have in your computer. Can you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of: (0) `sudo lspci` (1) `sudo lsusb` and (2) `sudo lshw -c network`. This will show a lot of detailed information about your hardware, making it easier to offer a specific solution.

Comment: I have added the outputs you mentioned.

Comment: Is the "TP-Link TL WN823N" the WiFi dongle that you've plugged in for network access?

Comment: Please [edit] to include `lspci -nnk | grep 2080 -A3`

Comment: Yes the TP-Link is the wifi dongle I am using. The dongle works, but when its unplugged there are no network devices available.
When I run lspci -nnk | grep 2080 -A3 there is no output at all.

Comment: I believe that @Someone meant to ask for: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` May we also see: `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I will make sure to post the outputs on Sunday. Also thanks.

Comment: I have added the output of 'sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio'. However, still no output for 'lscpi -nnk | grep 0280 -A3'

Comment: @milner236 I believe you are using the wrong command. It is `lspci` not `lscpi`. Please provide the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`. Prefer Copy/Paste. Thanks!

Comment: @Someone Still no output.. I even copied and paste.

Comment: We can only surmise that there is no built-in wireless device to activate. Sorry.

Comment: That's weird because when it came with Windows 10 Home, the wifi did work.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a setting in the BIOS/EFI to enable/disable wireless? Your `lspci` seems very brief; only six items. On my laptop, I get sixteen items including wireless. Please check again.